# https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/70435/what-is-a-both-sufficient-and-necessary-condition-for-not-treating-people-merely

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions, closed-questions, questions

I am trying to understand why the now editted [question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/70435/what-is-a-both-sufficient-and-necessary-condition-for-not-treating-people-merely) is still off-topic.

I am looking for a necessary and sufficient condition to classify some/any arbitrary treatment as a treatment merely as a means.

I think it is pretty on topic.